# How do I compress tinymce and all plugins into a static file?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

The [documentation](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Compressors3x) for tinymce notes that one can compress all the javascript and components (which I assume includes plugins) into a single file. They do note reasons why one might not want to that as well.

> #### Compressing into a static file
>
> It's also possible to simply concatenate the necessary components and some boilerplate code into a single .js file. However you will always have to recreate this file if you want to use other TinyMCE plugins, or you upgrade TinyMCE. You will also probably want to configure your webserver to compress javascript files.

But assuming one actually did want to do it, how does one actually go about it?  Build.xml does does not provide an appropriate task it seems.  At least when I tried it the plugins did not seem to be included when I loaded tiny_mce.js.

Comment: +1 very good question (we failed trying to make that work)

Comment: Are you looking for any solution to do this, or one that just uses the resources that come with TinyMCE. Could you use a server side language like PHP, for instance?

Answer (score 2):

There are some really excellent command line tools for this, but you can also do this easily with just a text editor. The simplest way is to just open each file, copy the contents, and paste the contents into a single JS file ("everything-all-together.js", say). You'll need to make sure you paste the files into the single file in the same order you would've put the script tags into the HTML doc. Once you have all the files all together, you can use tools like JSXMin, YUI Compressor, or Google Closure. There are also some tools online that do this, like http://www.minifyjavascript.com/. You can paste in the uncompressed JS and copy back out the compressed JS. This makes the build process really cumbersome, but if you just need to do this once, that will get you there.

The best way to do this is to do it as a build step for the site. That means when you make changes to the JS files, you rebuild the compressed JS file to include the changes as well. This can be a cumbersome step if you're iterating quickly and changing files over and over again. You don't want to have to rebuild the compressed file with each save. You can solve this by setting up development and production modes of the site. When being loaded in development mode, the JS files aren't grouped together. When all the necessary changes are made, you'd rerun the build step to generate the single compressed JS file. To do the minification from the command line, you'd probably want to use Google Closure: https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/. If you download the compiler app, you can do the following:

> java -jar compiler.jar some-file.js some-other-file.js > compiled.js

That will generate a file called compiled.js that includes the contents of some-file.js and some-other-file.js in a minified format. You can specify as many files to compile as you need to. Actually, I'm selling Closure a bit short to say it's just minified. It's also extremely optimized code. Pretty much every site *should* be doing this to all of there JS all the time unless they're already doing something better.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm getting you (and the tinymce docs) right, but this sounds a lot like combining JavaScript files on the server side. This means taking the contents of all of your JS files, putting them into one file and returning that one to the client.

*Why* would you do that? Well, this should be obvious, but.. you reduce the number of HTTP requests to your server, which is always a good thing.

*How* do you do that? There are many solutions out there for all server-side languages and frameworks, I suggest doing a Google search for "[your language] javascript minifier" or something similar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am aware of those, they don't work in this case.  TinyMce is hard coded to dynamically load some of its functionality from the server I believe.